# Gremlin edge insert from complex map structure input using inject()

Tags: gremlin

I have a set of vertices (Role & Identity) that are indexed by a unique `sid` property. I want to inject  a list input of the form below where the map values represent a single role `sid` and an array of identity `sid` and use this to generate edges between existing vertices (which definitely exist and definitely have a matching `sid` property). Note the map can be quite large.

```
 g.inject([["role":"3", "identities":["6","7"]],["role":"1", "identities":["5","6","7"]]])
```

In the example above, the first element should generate 2 edges [Role:3]->[Identity:6] and [Role:3]->[Identity:7].

I have tried multiple combinations of unfold(), map(), etc but just cannot get the correct result. Any assistance would be very appreciated!

Comment: Have you seen the fairly new `mergeE` and `mergeV` steps that were added to Gremlin as part of the 3.6.x line? Those steps make this kind of insert much easier. The trickiest part today is that you cannot write `V(select('x'))` where `x` comes from the map and represents a vertex ID. You end up writing quite complex, and not always performant, `where...by` type queries. Using `mergeE` you may be able to avoid much of this complexity by just injecting the map a slightly different way.